# Improving compilation times of a monolithic .NET assembly - incremental compilation?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation

We are using .NET Framework 4.6 and currently have a monolithic DLL containing most of our application. It comes in at about 700k lines of code. Any time we make a change it takes over a minute to recompile. We would like to speed this up if possible.

One option is to break the monolith into multiple peer assemblies, none of which would depend upon each other (except for a single Common assembly for code shared between the projects). So if the changes are restricted to a single assembly, the compiler has only to recompile this smaller DLL. Further, these peer assemblies could be compiled in parallel, again potentially reducing compilation time.

Others have suggested that the new "incremental build" features of .NET Core 2.x can radically increase build times of the monolith, the implication being that the compiler can rebuild only the parts of the monolith that have changed, while ignoring the rest.

*Is this truly the case, or is this not how the new incremental build feature works?*

Or does anyone have any other advice on the best way to improve our compilation times?

Comment: "One option is to break the monolith into multiple peer assemblies, so if the changes are restricted to a single assembly, the compiler has only to recompile this smaller DLL." don't be so sure of that. I worked in a project when this was done so bad that a single change implied recompiling 5 projects due to dependencies and took well over 3 minutes. And it didn't even have 50k LOC

Comment: I guess the operative word here is "peer" - none of the assemblies we propose to break the monolith into will depend on each other. They would be leaves in the compilation tree. So my assumption is that a change to a peer should be isolated from the others, and therefore only require recompilation of the peer itself. Is this not correct? Could you share more about your experience?

Comment: That's why I said it went wrong :) as long as they don't have dependencies, you *should* be OK

Comment: @MikeChamberlain: For what it's worth, what you are proposing here sounds complete standard to me. We have several huge apps that consist of (sometimes) hundreds of separate assemblies, with none of the build issues that Camilo hints at.

Comment: Incremental build feature or not, if a monolith has 'components' that are non related, I feel they should be moved into separate components just going by the [SOLID's S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). However, the 'no dependency scenario' this seems unlikely from what I understand, and even in this case I still feel that the SOLID principles could be applied for a better performance, structuring and maintenance of the app.

Comment: Sounds obvious but you can quickly improve things with better hardware. Otherwise, separating a 700Kloc binary into multiple binaries is also very common (but can be a lot of work, of course), not only to build in parallel, but it's also a a matter of scaling the organization at every level of the process (plan, design, dev, tests, ship, etc. ownership of binaries). It's should be easier for everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Incremental builds](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/UWP/net-native2.0/incremental-compilation.md) may help you with your single monolithic DLL.  In 2.0 they were introduced but it was mainly focused on detecting dependency changes - something that Visual Studio is already doing for you in your case.

**However**, from [What's New in .NET Core 2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-2-1):

> Use of long-running SDK build servers, which are processes that span across individual dotnet build invocations. They eliminate the need to JIT-compile large blocks of code every time dotnet build is run.

I'm currently unable to test exactly what this could mean for a large project building and having small areas of isolated code changing, but I would suggest experimenting with it.

**Update**, I tried to test exactly what this could mean but unfortunately don't have a 700k line project to test with.  I used [this MS example project](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb) and ran 2 copies - one combined into a single dll and the other left split up.  Every test I did, the sample "monolithic" combined project ran faster, but I'm assuming these are invalid results since the combined project is hardly considered "monolithic".

One interesting thing I found in this sample "monolith": whether I made a small change to a view, or sweeping changes to the project, I never saw a difference between fresh compile times.  This makes me question exactly what this new build-server thing is caching with the JIT stuff.  Perhaps again, this is just because my "monolith" is not large.

In the end, I can find no proof that your truly monolith project will provide faster builds during changes on .NET Core 2.1.  I **can** see proof that splitting it up into a couple of functional projects **will** provide benefits.  Bottom line is, projects that haven't changed won't be recompiled.

In the end, in your case, you have a monolithic DLL and that is a major part of the problem.  All of the other things you and others suggest in the comments will greatly increase your build time since if some key areas of code, which are changed infrequently, can be broken out into other project(s) they will not be rebuilt on every compile.  If they change **very** infrequently they could even be pulled into a nuget package and hosted on a private nuget server.  Then they wouldn't be compiled - even on brand new dev envs.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with breaking it up. But there are many ways to break up a solution. I think you should do it in phases.

#### Phase 1 - The fastest way to break it up now.

Most common ways to get the fastest results:

1. All Models - Create a Models library project and move all your model files to it. Have your monolith reference the models project. Do not change the files or namespaces at all. Just cut and paste from one project to the other. If any model classes were private, make them internal (find and replace in project) and add InternalsVisibleTo attribute to your monolith's assembly. Estimated time to move all model classes: 20 minutes.
2. All Interfaces - Create an interfaces library project and move all your interface class files to it. Have your monolith reference the models project. Do not change the files or namespaces at all. Just cut and paste from one project to the other. If any interface classes were private, make them internal (find and replace in project) and add InternalsVisibleTo attribute to your monolith's assembly. Estimated time to move all interface classes: 20 minutes.
3. Generated Code - Create a GeneratedCode project. Move all classes that are 100% generated code to this project. Of course, it is an assumption that because you have 700k lines of code, a lot of the classes are entirely generated. If you have no generated code, skip this one. Estimated time to move all generated code: 1 hour.
4. Extension methods - Create an Extension project, and move all your extension method classes to this project. Estimated time to move all model classes: 30 minutes.
5. FixedLogic - Create a fixed logic project. Find all your rarely touched classes - In a project his size, there are probably hundreds of class files that haven't been touched in years. You are recompiling these classes over and over again for no reason whatsoever. You have to figure out which those are. Hopefully you can see this easily in your source control. Estimated Time: 2 hours to figure out the query in your source control. 10 minutes to move those files to a new project.
6. Stay at 1 dll for your release. Now, I assume you have a build, deploy, install process. If you don't, ignore this step. If you do, and it is complex, you may *not* want to add dlls to your existing processes, because that would add additional time to these tasks. So make sure that all the files compile in a way that still results in 1 dll. See this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-build-a-multifile-assembly. Estimated time to implement this article: 4 hours.

Primary Goal: After first build, subsequent builds only build projects with changes, decreasing your build time significantly.

#### Phase 2 - A better but long term way.

Take your time to break your code up in a way that makes senese. Do this only when you touch code anyway.

1. Analyze your poject and make a list of areas or domains that your code covers. This is just a simple list in a text file. You probably have about a lot of domains.
2. Assign class files to those domains, but also mark the class files as Model, Interface, Logic.
3. Next time you touch a file in a domain, create three projects: Domain.Models, Domain.Interfaces and Domain.Logic. Move the code into the correct project.

Primary Goal - Separation of Concerns

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to move away from the monolithic design and think about putting parts that belong together into separate assemblies - so this is the way I recommend you to go.

The way you can achieve this is (in Visual Studio 2015 - 2017):

1. Open your solution
2. For each assembly you want to add, create a separate project within your solution (**right-click** on the solution to open the context-menu, then select **add --> new project ...** in the context menu, then select **Visual C# -> Class Library**)
3. Add a reference to your main project (which is your monolithic application) for every assembly you've created (**right-click** on references, then select **add reference ...** and browse the **Projects --> solution** navigator to select it)
4. Right-click on the main project, and select **Build Dependencies -> Project Dependencies...** In the dialog, ensure your main project is selected in the dropdown. Tick-mark every assembly that you have added. Now your main project is dependent on the assemblies and will compile in the right order.
5. Move classes from your main project into the assembly projects (cut and paste them). If that creates any additional dependencies, open  **Build Dependencies -> Project Dependencies...**, this time on the project that depends on different assemblies, and tick mark the assemblies it depends on.
6. Right-click on the solution and select **rebuild the solution.** If you've done everything right, then compilation should succeed. Otherwise, fix any errors coming up (for example due to missing references). Check if you missed any `using` statements to import namespaces.

From now on, you only need to build an assembly if it has changed (right-click on the project, and select "build"). If there are any dependencies, the compiler automatically compiles it in the right build order.

Because you've broken the monolithic design into smaller assemblies, each of them compiles very quickly and you need to re-compile only those that have changed.

Those that don't depend on other assemblies can compile in parallel - so if you want to run different compiler processes you can think about creating a batch that does this. The project dependencies dialog helps you identifying assemblies that can be compiled in parallel.

The Build Order tab shows you in which order they should run, the Dependencies tab shows for each assembly which other assemblies it depends on. This way you can find out if there are any "branches" that can be compiled in parallel to other "branches" (with "branch" I don't mean source controlled branches, but branches of your solution: think of a tree where the main project is the root - each branch consists of a sequence of assemblies of your solution that can compile in parallel).